# Find common element using recursive and return as vector

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I am trying to find common elements of two arrays but I am getting false results.

Where is my mistake? It seems like everything is normal.

```
template<class T>
bool contains(T arr,int size, int num){
    for(int i=0; i<size;++i)
        if(arr[i] == num)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

I am trying to use tail recursion:

```
template <class T>
vector<T> cElemet(T ar1[], int s1, T ar2[], int s2){

    vector<T> v;


    if(s1 > 0) 
        v = cElemet(ar1,s1-1,ar2,s2);


    if(contains(ar2,s2,ar1[s1-1])){
        cout << "+" << ar1[s1-1] ; 
        v.push_back(ar1[s1-1]);
    }

    return v;
}
int main(){
    
    int ar1[6] = {1,5,6,7,2,4};
    int ar2[6] = {6,3,9,4,5,8};

    std::vector<int> v = cElemet(ar1,6,ar2,6);

    cout <<endl;
    for(auto a : v)
        cout << a << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works for me. I don't know what problem you think there is with it.

Comment: Undefined behaviour (*vide infra*) can **seem** to work, sometimes.

Comment: When I ran OP's code as presented (MSVC) I had this output: `8 5 6 4`

Comment: Why isn't `ar1` and `ar2` also `std::vector`s? Try rewriting the code with vectors and range-based for loops and you would never make this mistake in the first place.

Comment: That's not tail recursion - a tail call is the last thing that happens in a function. (And even if you rewrote it, the presence of destructors in C++ can easily turn what looks like tail calls into not-tail calls.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'recursion end' condition is "off-by-one" – it should be `if (s1 > 1)` instead of `if (s1 > 0)`.

As it stands, you end up calling `cElemet` with a value of `0` (from`s1 - 1`) and then, in that recursion, you attempt to access `ar1[s1 - 1]` when `s1` is zero, which causes undefined behaviour.

Changing your function to the following fixes the problem – for your sample arrays (even when I tested by jumbling up the data values). However, there may be issues for arrays of size `1`.

```cpp
template <class T>
vector<T> cElemet(T ar1[], int s1, T ar2[], int s2)
{
    vector<T> v;
    if (s1 > 1) // Don't call recursively when s1 is 1 ...
        v = cElemet(ar1, s1 - 1, ar2, s2);

    if (contains(ar2, s2, ar1[s1 - 1])) { // ... or we have UB here.
        cout << "+" << ar1[s1 - 1];
        v.push_back(ar1[s1 - 1]);
    }
    return v;
}
```